# I have an image that leads to an external link, but after I move the image down, the link can't be clicked anymore

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

The hyperlink works just fine when the `top: 740px;` code isn't there, but as soon as I move the image down, the link can't be clicked anymore. What can I do so that the external link moves down with the image and can still be clicked on?

```html
<style> 
position: relative; 
width:700px;
float: right;
height:400px;
top: 740px;     
</style> 
    

<div class="youtube">
    <a href="https://youtube.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.jpeg" alt="youtube">
    </a>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed declaring class in  css

```
 <style>
 .youtube {    /* or other class name for which you needed this css */
      position: relative; 
      width:700px;
      float: right;
      height:400px;
      top: 740px;
   }
  </style>
```

Comment: nope, nothing changed. I believe it has to do with the image moving somehow, because if I take out the `top: 740px;`, it works just fine.